# How to tell if python instance was compiled as framework?

Tags: python, macos

How can one tell if a given instance of Python (on OS X) was compiled with the `--enable-framework` flag?

The one thing I tried is not entirely conclusive:

```
% python -c 'import sysconfig, pprint; pprint.pprint(sysconfig.get_config_vars())' | grep -i framework
 'LIBS': '-ldl  -framework CoreFoundation',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': '',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR': 'no-framework',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR': '',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX': '',
 'RESSRCDIR': 'Mac/Resources/framework',
 'SHLIBS': '-ldl  -framework CoreFoundation',
 'WITH_NEXT_FRAMEWORK': 0,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive test for an OS X framework build:

```
./configure --enable-framework ...
```

is the presence of `PYTHONFRAMEWORK` in the Python build config variables.   This idiom is used throughout the Python standard library:

```
if get_config_var("PYTHONFRAMEWORK"):
    # framework build
```

See for example, [this test](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.3.0/Lib/sysconfig.py) at line 221 in the `sysconfig` module itself.